# XML sitemap for react app

Tags: reactjs, xml, xml-sitemap

I have a react app for which I want to add a sitemap.xml. I have added this route to link to the file (XML is my my sitemap.xml):

```
import XML from './sitemap.xml';    
<Route component={XML} path={'/sitemap.xml'} />
```

I keep getting this error, which I understand it means that I need to add an xml loader to my webpack:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

Not sure how to pick an xml loader as I could mostly find parsers (xml to json) and I am not sure if it's ok to have the sitemap in json. Also, is there any other native way of displaying the xml file without adding any loader?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using create-react-app, just put your XML file in public folder (a folder beside node_modules and src folders), then access it through `{base_url}/{XML_file_name.xml}` (e.g. `localhost:3000/sitemap.xml`)

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. Plain and simple!

Comment: on localhost, my sitemap.xml is accessible through http://localhost:3000/sitemap,XML but when I deploy this app onto AWS amplify, it is not accessible through {baseURL}/{sitemap.xml} any suggestion?

Comment: for amplify, you would need to add a redirect rule, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html

Answer (score 1):

In , keyword component should be a React Component.

Check the documentation：[Route - React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md)

---

If you want to pass XML as a variable, you should change XML format to string and with another prop but `component={}`.To transform XML to String, ry `escape(XML)` before passing to Route! Check [escape(str)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape)

---

with `import` keyword, youcan try like this:

```js
// file: get-xml.js
let transformXMLToString = () => {

  // read the target XML fiel and transform it to String
  
  // return the string
  return XMLasString;
};

export transformXMLToString;

// then you could import the XML like this in another file:

import transformXMLToString from 'get-xml.js';

// then pass it to <Route> like:

<Route component={transformXMLToString()}/>
```

Comment: sorry, i am not sure how this is exactly done. I have updated the route with the way I am importing the xml, in case you can help with that line, or maybe any link that would help with this?

Comment: That I mean is to trying transform XML to string type and passing to Route as a string, then transform the string back to XML type! @aiiwa

Comment: well, tried escape as suggested (although its documented as deprecated), but it didnt work.

Comment: and why you passing XML to Route as `component={XML}` ?

Comment: in `<Route path="/" component={App}>`, keyword `component` should be a React Component.

Comment: thanks. tried that. still give me error: Module parse failed: xxx\sitemap.xml Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to add
`<a href="XML_PATH" style={{display:"none"}}>xml</a>`
Then check your google chrome development console, search for the anchor(a) tag.
And follow the path