# react-router-sitemap doesn't generate urls for dynamic content from list

Tags: reactjs, react-router, server-side, sitemap

We are using [react-router-sitemap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-sitemap) for creating sitemap dynamically. We got stuck with adding routes dynamically from our blog. Code returns output correctly, but doesn't add article links to the sitemap, here is the code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './homePage/HomePage';
import Projects from './projects/Projects';
import Project from './projects/MobileProject/project/Project';
import Contact from './contact/Contact';
import Job from './job/Job';
import Blog from './blog/Blog';


const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const API = "http://wp.mysite.in.ua";

function generatePostsRoutes() {
    console.log("generating posts ...");
    let posts = [];

    fetch(API + "/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
        .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(content => {
                posts = content;
                console.log(posts.map((value) => <Route exact path={"/blog/article/" + value.slug} component={Blog} />));

                if(posts.length !== 0) {
                    return (
                        posts.map((value) => <Route exact path={"/blog/article/" + value.slug} component={Blog} />)
                    );
                }
            });
}

export default (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
        <Route exact path="/projects" component={Projects}/>
        <Route exact path="/project" component={Project}/>
        <Route exact path="/blog" component={Blog}/>
        <Route exact path="/blog/:sortId" component={Blog}/>
        {
            generatePostsRoutes()
        }
        <Route exact path="/job" component={Job}/>
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
    </Switch>
);
```

Here is our sitemap we wanna add blog links after `<url> <loc>http://mysite.in.ua/blog/:sortId</loc> </url>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
xmlns:news="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9" 
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:mobile="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-mobile/1.0" 
xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" 
xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
<url> <loc>http://mysite.in.ua/</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>http://mysite.in.ua/</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>http://mysite.in.ua/projects</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>http://mysite.in.ua/project</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>http://mysite.in.ua/blog</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>http://mysite.in.ua/blog/:sortId</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>http://mysite.in.ua/job</loc> </url>
<url> <loc>http://mysite.in.ua/contact</loc> </url>
</urlset>
```

Thank you for your time, I would be so glad if you can help us)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XML sitemap for react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382193/xml-sitemap-for-react-app)

Comment: Is there any way to make sitemap.xml  based on "react-router-dom" router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-router-sitemap` provides a way to generate url for dynamic contents.
On step 6 of the [How to generate a sitemap for your React website with dynamic content](https://www.amitsn.com/blog/how-to-generate-a-sitemap-for-your-react-website-with-dynamic-content) it show how to add dynamic contents

Comment: `react-router-sitemap` doesn't work with the latest versions of React. You can use `react-router-sitemap-generator`